# Robot framework - java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: python, azure-devops, robotframework

I have created an Azure pipeline and in one of the tasks I am testing my application using Robot framework. I am using `cx_oracle 7.2.0` module to support my testing using Robot. When I run the task of the pipeline I get the error

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

What I assume is the error is due to JRE compatibility issue. The version of JRE on the Azure VM 1.7 . 
However, I can run the same framework without any issues on my local machine which has JRE 1.8 .
I have two questions now.

Can I upgrade the java version to 1.8 on the Azure VM using any task and then run my application.If so how? If not, how can I manage to get the cx_oracle module compatible for java 1.7?

Please note that both my local machine and Azure VM has python 3.x which is sufficient for cx_oracle module.

Comment: Upgrade the JVM. *Of course* you can  do it. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: If all you're really asking is how to install a JRE, it's documented.

Comment: @user207421, upgrading the JVM? How do you think is that possible with Azure Devops? Also can you please ask what is unclear to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a task named ‘Java tool Installer’, use this task in a build or release pipeline to acquire a specific version of Java. Here is the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/java-tool-installer?view=azure-devops).

I run this task in my build pipeline and successful update my java version from openjdk version ‘9.0.4’ to ‘java version ‘1.8.0_221’.
[image]

I download the Java SE Runtime Environment 8u221 windows x64 and upload it to my repo. You can download different Java version from other operating systems in https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html.

In addition, if you are using Azure VM, you can download the RDP File and update the version manually.

Comment: It is still not working for me. Error is `##[error]Specified JDK source file does not have a supported file extension.
`. Did you place the zip file or just the exe file in the `JDK file` column? Should I include the path of the file or file name also? I have downloaded the JRE not the JDK , if that matters.

Comment: I used the jre-8u221-windows-x64.tar.gz file in JDK file.